# Confusion about Stateless Strategies

Tags: design-patterns

In Strategy design pattern, stateless strategies are mentioned. Could anyone please help me to understand it by answering following question:

1. What is this stateless strategy ?
2. What problem does it solve and how ?
3. Where to use & not use this ?
4. Dis(a)dvantages for same

And I will highly appreciate if all this could be explained by giving an example.

Comment: *In Strategy design pattern, stateless strategies are mentioned*. Link or quote please. That being said, a stateless strategy is a  concrete implementation of a Strategy interface that does not have any state. :)

Comment: Consequences of Strategy Pattern as per Gang of Four books :     Increased number of objects.Strategies increase the number of objects in an application. Sometimesyou can reduce this overhead by implementing strategies as statelessobjects that contexts can share. Any residual state is maintained by thecontext, which passes it in each request to the Strategy object. Sharedstrategies should not maintain state across invocations. The Flyweight (218) pattern describes this approach in moredetail.

Answer (score 6):

**What is this stateless strategy?**

A stateless strategy is one where each "run" of the strategy does not affect other "runs".

Here are two strategies for picking `true` or `false`:

```
public final class FlipStrategy {

    private boolean lastPick;

    public boolean pick() {

        lastPick = !lastPick;

        return lastPick;
    }
}
```

and...

```
public final class RandomStrategy {

    public boolean pick() {

        return (new Random()).nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

`FlipStrategy` is a stateful-strategy. The result you get depends on previous results.

`RandomStrategy` is a stateless-strategy. The results you get are independent of each-other.

**What problem does it solve and how?**

Stateless-strategies...

- can be safely shared without one user altering the results of another
- are (typically) thread-safe, allowing them to be shared between threads
- have less memory overhead, since one instance can be reused multiple times
- can be created on an ad-hoc basis, which can make program architecture simpler

**Where to use & not use this?**

It is not always possible to use a stateless-strategy. Imagine a strategy for a bouncer - it must remember how many people have already gone in to decide if more people should be allowed to enter.

Otherwise, stateless-strategies are better.

Sometimes, you can turn a stateful-strategy into a stateless one using a "context" object. A context object encodes all state relevant to a strategy into a parameter.

In our previous example, the context might be:

```
public final class Context { 

    public final boolean lastPick;

    public Context(final boolean lastPick) {

        this.lastPick = lastPick;
    }

    // hashCode etc... 
}
```

Now `FlipStrategy` can be implemented in a stateless way:

```
public final class FlipStrategy {

    public boolean pick(final Context context) {

        return !context.lastPick;
    }
}
```

Using a context object is arguably a cleaner design. The last pick is a property of the world, not the strategy, so it should not be a member of it.